# Convert long javascript element codes into smaller ones

Tags: javascript

I have been looking for this (and trying by myself) but so far couldn't make it work.

I have the following  that onClick it triggers a toggle function:

```
function toogle(){
    document.getElementById('id1').style.top = (document.getElementById('id1').style.top != '-130px' ? '-130px' : '0px')}
```

It works as I wanted but I would also like to make it a bit short, I tried doing

```
var smalltag = document.getElementById('id1').style.top;
smalltag  = (smalltag  != '-130px' ? '-130px' : '0px')

or

var smalltag = "document.getElementById('id1').style.top";
smalltag  = (smalltag  != '-130px' ? '-130px' : '0px')
```

but none worked, how can I make it work? Also would like a brief explanation so I can understand it better (if possible).

Forgot to say, I do not intent to use any javascript packages, I am trying to learn the javascript as best as I can and using such packages would be a bad way to do so (meaning no jquery, mootools, etc).

Thank you for yout attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `smalltag` as reference to DOM element so you need to do like this:

```
var smalltag = document.getElementById('id1');
smalltag.style.top  = (smalltag.style.top  != '-130px' ? '-130px' : '0px')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it makes more sense to me. I will choose yours as the answer because you were the first to answer. Just got to wait 10 minutes to do so, thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to avoid getting multiple times the element by its id

```
var element = document.getElementById('id1');
element.style.top = (element.style.top != '-130px') ? '-130px' : '0px';
```

Comment: Why don't you do something to avoid getting multiple times the style from the element?

Comment: I am curious about what bergi asked too.

Comment: Because calling document.getElementById() has an overhead, I don't think retrieving a field of a structure has such an impact overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You are just assigning to the `smalltag` variable, giving it a new value which is irrelevant to the `StyleDeclaration` object you actually want to change. In JavaScript there are (luckily?) no pointers, so you always need to assign to a property:

```
var elstyle = document.getElementById('id1').style;
elstyle.top = elstyle.top != '-130px' ? '-130px' : '0px';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the actual element in your variable so you can change its properties later on. You were trying to store the string and than amend it, but it will have no impact on the actual element.

```
var el = document.getElementById('id1');
el.style.top = (el.style.top != '-130px' ? '-130px' : '0px')
```

Comment: You don't want to change any properties of the element, so there is no need to store it in a variable.

Comment: So in the end I was retrieving the "top" value and storing into a string, I love learning these things. Thanks Jakub!

Answer (score 1):

```
var smalltag = document.getElementById('id1').style.top;
var small  = (smalltag  != '-130px' ? '-130px' : '0px');
```

Comment: nah man i copied, edited and answered it correct! Because i was in hurry!

Comment: Ah, you really edited it. Yet the OP does not want the value in a new variable, but assign it to the `top` property.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry Man, If I knew that he wants tiny code then i honestly say i will not have answered!

Answer (score 1):

In the first one which you said it worked, the document.getElementById('id1').style.top was getting reset.

But in second attempt you are not setting the document.getElementById('id1').style.top again from smalltag